# nested tag on opennlp

Tags: java, opennlp

Hey I'm trying to make a training data for opennlp to detect location name within sentences. I get stuck at something like this :

```
<START:location> <START:location> North Manchester <END> Hospital <END>
```

I really need to detect those two object, the name of the hospital and the city name. What I can do to achive that?

I'm using opennlp library version 1.6 on java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you formatted your tags definitely won't work the way you are thinking, because the outer tag will take the contents of the inner tag string literally as far as I know (and you'll basically never get a hit on something that weird). I would just duplicate the sentence with two different tags, one for the city name, and one for the hospital. Also, you really should have more context around those tags in your sentence (use complete sentences if you can).

At some point, you'll have to start thinking semantics, because in terms of Entity Extraction ontological thinking, a hospital is not a location entity, it can only be related to one. Just a thought, kind of academic, but interesting if it's relevant.